# How to assess private function "unnest_tweets" in vosanSML package for R 4.3.1?

Tags: function, package

I tried the below code to assess the private function "unnest_tweets" from vosanSML package. However, the code didn't work. it has the error msg below.

df2 <- df %>% vosonSML:::unnest_tweets(word, tweet) %>% anti_join(stopwords2) %>% count(word, sort=TRUE)

Error in anti_join(., stopwords2) : object 'unnest_tweets' not found

Can someon help with this error? Is there another way to  Million thanks!!

I tried to delete the anti_join and the count function, but using the "unnest_tweets" alone, it doesn't work.